# Microsoft Visual Studio - Strange behavior in C when using the "static" keyword on arrays larger than roughly 100 kbytes

Tags: static

### PREFACE

I'm facing a strange problem with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Professional edition.

I'm writing a C program that has 22 source files.

Each source file declares a char array of 100 KBytes in size.

Since I'm lazy I gave all the arrays the same name and therefore I had to put the keyword "static" in front of each declaration in order to limit the linking scope.

All the arrays are not initialized.

### PROBLEM

The debugger enters the main() function which calls another function that writes in one of those arrays.

I inspect the array with the debugger and realize that the array is not written at all.

Here's the source code:

```
static char my_array[1024 * 100];

void my_function (void)
{
    int dummy;

    my_array[0] = 'a';

    my_array[1] = 'b';
    
    /*
     * I have a break point on "dummy = 100;" in order to inspect the content 
     * of my_array[0] and my_array[1]
     *
     * The debugger tells me that both my_array[0] and my_array[1] are dirty 
     * and don't contain 'a' nor 'b'
     */ 
    dummy = 100;
}
```

If I remove the keyword "static" and rename those 22 arrays the problem disappear and all works fine.

Can anybody help me out?

Enrico Migliore

Answer (score 0):

it was a mistake of mine.

In a function I forgot to fclose() a file.

All is working just fine.

Enrico Migliore